# Merging two arrays into a single array of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a json list variable like this:

```
['2023-07-18', '2023-07-19', '2023-07-20', '2023-07-21', '2023-07-22', '2023-07-23', '2023-07-24']
```

and another one like this:

```
[36263, 31926, 30988, 31304, 27971, 27376, 7479]
```

I need to add them to be one dictionary variable with a loop in Python.

The expected output should look like this:

```
{'Date':'2023-07-18','Fees':'36263'}
{'Date':'2023-07-19','Fees':'30988'}
{'Date':'2023-07-20','Fees':'30988'}
```

I tried using a `for` loop with the `len` of the variable but my output is something like this.

```
{'2023-07-18': 36263, '2023-07-19': 31926, '2023-07-20': 30988, '2023-07-21': 31304, '2023-07-22': 27971, '2023-07-23': 27376, '2023-07-24': 7479}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful If you provided the code you are currently using to do this.

Comment: What is the logic that you're trying to implement here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: You say you want to "add them in one dictionary variable" and then show the desired output as three dictionaries. And not even in another data structure like a list. The output you don't like is "one dictionary variable". Post the code you have so far and clarify the desired output. One dict? A list of dicts?

Comment: Solved it by adding the key in append variable

Comment: `Data=[] for project in response["ResultsByTime"]:         data.append({'Date': project['TimePeriod']['Start'], 'Fees': round(float(project['Total']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']))})`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing this would be using a `for` loop with `zip()`.

```
dates = ['2023-07-18', '2023-07-19', '2023-07-20', '2023-07-21', '2023-07-22', '2023-07-23', '2023-07-24']
fees = [36263, 31926, 30988, 31304, 27971, 27376, 7479]

res = []

for (date, fee) in zip(dates, fees):
    res.append({
        'date': date,
        'fee': str(fee)
    });
    
print(res)
```

The output of this code:

```
[{'date': '2023-07-18', 'fee': '36263'},
 {'date': '2023-07-19', 'fee': '31926'},
 {'date': '2023-07-20', 'fee': '30988'},
 {'date': '2023-07-21', 'fee': '31304'},
 {'date': '2023-07-22', 'fee': '27971'},
 {'date': '2023-07-23', 'fee': '27376'},
 {'date': '2023-07-24', 'fee': '7479'}]
```

Here I am just printing the result to the console. In your case, you might turn it back into JSON or whatever you need.

Comment: Thank you @michal-gogas, it has opened up some new ways for me to conclude this task.
Apologies if wasn't clear enough, solve this by adding keys in append.

`Data=[]
for project in response["ResultsByTime"]:
        data.append({'Date': project['TimePeriod']['Start'], 'Fees': round(float(project['Total']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']))})`